# Clicking on a plot in Octave closes Octave

Tags: plot, jpeg, octave

I just downloaded Octave today and I have used a little bit of Matlab. I am working on a machine learning problem and one of the things I wanted to do was opening a JPEG file in Octave as a matrix.

```
I = imread('nameOfTheFile.JPEG');
imshow(I)
```

This opens a figure with the image I was looking at. I clicked on the image out of habit and the figure closed along with Octave. I'm not sure why and it seems very inconvenient. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: As long as you don't click on the [X] in the corner this shouldn't happen. You should fill a bug report on http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/octave . Please add operating system, your octave version, on windows also if it's a MXE, MinGW or cygwin build and the code needed to reproduce your problem

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for your help, could it be due to image format or something like that? Also,

    I=imread('nameOfTheFile.JPEG')

I get 

    warning: your version of GraphicsMagick limits images to 8 bits
    per pixel
    warning: called from
    imformats>default_formats at line 256 column 11
    imformats at line 79 column 3
    imageIO at line 106 column 11
    imread at line 106 column 30

Comment: No, the warning above only means that your GraphicsMagick was build with-quantum-depth=8. See here: http://wiki.octave.org/GraphicsMagick

Comment: Just as reference, this is the bug: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45566